# Learn 64bit Assembly from 32bit Instruction

Tags: assembly

I've been trying to use the Hacking: Art of Deception book to learn assembly and programming.  It has a great programming section that gives you a greater appreciation for the inner workings of the program and gives you a greater understanding of how being precise when programming is important.  However, I've been having a hard time following along because the book uses 32bit examples and I use a 64bit system.  I know how to compile with gcc to 32bit, or I also tune down to the 32bit cd provided with the book, but I think I'd rather learn 64bit because it is probably more relevant than 32bit systems are(or becoming increasingly more relevant?).  So basically what I'm trying to ask is if I should even bother trying to use this book to figure out 64bit assembly, because I have heard it is much different, or if I should find other material to learn 64bit assembly separately?  If there are any easy to understand books that cover 64bit intel assembly, I'd be grateful for a reference.

Comment: So, are we talking x86 and x64 here? Probably, yes? If so, they're really not that different at all. Essentially the same, really. Less of a change than 16bit to 32bit was.

Comment: I don't think this forum is the right place for this question

Comment: This is opinion based, but my opinion is that if you already have a book to learn 32-bit assembly and you're not a huge wiz at assembly yet, it's worth learning. Then learn  64-bit and you'll understand and appreciate the differences more. It will overall enrich your experience. But you can't use a 32-bit assembly book to learn 64-bit assembly language.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Like Lurker said in the above comment. Since you have a book for 32-bit, learn it. 32-bit is still very relevant.

Once you learn how 32-bit works, then the following rundown of what 64-bit adds will be a breeze.

> The number of registers has been doubled to 16.
>
> All registers are 64 bits long. The 64-bit extensions of the IA32 registers are named %rax, %rcx, %rdx, %rbx, %rsi, %rdi, %rsp, and %rbp. The new registers are named %r8–%r15.
>
> The low-order 32 bits of each register can be accessed directly. This gives us the familiar registers from IA32: %eax, %ecx, %edx, %ebx, %esi, %edi, %esp, and %ebp, as well as eight new 32-bit registers: %r8d–%r15d.
>
> The low-order 16 bits of each register can be accessed directly, as is the case for IA32. The word-size versions of the new registers are named %r8w–%r15w.
>
> The low-order 8 bits of each register can be accessed directly. This is true in IA32 only for the first four registers (%al, %cl, %dl, %bl). The byte-size versions of the other IA32 registers are named %sil, %dil, %spl, and %bpl. The byte-size versions of the new registers are named %r8b–%r15b.
>
> For backward compatibility, the second byte of registers %rax, %rcx, %rdx, and %rbx can be directly accessed by instructions having single-byte operands.

Text from [Computer Systems
A Programmer’s Perspective](http://jarson.asia/resource/CSAPP.pdf)